# How do remove the extra div wrapper

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, less

Is it possible to disable react disable react extra div wrapper?
I'm using ES2015.

The wrapper is making two of my style  not centering my component in C#.

```
#First div
.default-content {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
}

#second div
.full-width {
    width:100%;
}
```

The code looks like this when its rendered.:

```
    <react-container params="component: MontelUI.React.CompactStory, args: { 
     newsId: 955888, userId: 1003465, bookmarkMainProp: false  }">
       <div>
           <div>hei</div>
       </div>
    </react-container>
```

My render function looks like this:

```
render() {

    return (
        <div>hei</div>
    )
```

The component is called through custom-tag.

Answer (score 3):

Use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to enclose the content.

```
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>hei</React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: @KhoaLe You'll need React 16 to use `Fragment`

Comment: @LucaFabbri    

`moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-animate-on-change": "1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-modal": "3.1.2`

Seems like I got this, any opinion?

Comment: Yes, you should have `Fragment`. How are you importing it and which error you get?

Comment: @LucaFabbri the error I'm getting is that Fragment is not a type of react. Something you know about?

Comment: `import { Fragment } from 'react'`

It says types/react/index has no exported member  'Fragment'

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you are really using react 16.4, or you have some other strange build behavior.

Comment: `<react-container params="component: comp"/>`

I'm calling on the component like this in cshtml.